# How GCDAsyncSocket has identified end of an incoming message

Tags: ios, gcdasyncsocket

It easy to understand that we can use following ways to identify the end of an incoming message, for example:
1. Putting the length of the message before the data itself
2. Using a separator

However, GCDAsyncSocket provides a more comprehensive/smarter/general solution. And it seems that it uses low level's TCP protocol to identify the begin and end of a message.

How does it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCDAsyncSocket just uses TCP streams.  TCP streams do not inherently define "messages", they are, as the name implies, just streams of bytes.

GCDAsyncSocket adds some convenience methods to make things a bit easier for you

- `readDataToLength:withTimeout:tag:` and associated methods automatically complete the read when the specified number of bytes have been received - This can be used with the first option you mentioned.
- `readDataToData:withTimeout:tag:` that allow you to specify the terminator sequence and have the read complete automatically when it is received  - This is the second option you mentioned.

There is nothing inherent in TCP to support these functions as such, the authors of GCDAsyncSocket have simply implemented these solutions on top of the raw stream.

Comment: Thanks so much. My question is how can GCDAsyncSocket know when is the end of a message if there're two consecutive messages incoming. "Seperator" is defined  by the server and GCDAsyncSocket as a general solution, obviously does not know what "Seperator" is.

Comment: You have to specify the separator/terminator in your call to `readDataToData`